# R: Deep Neural Network with Custom Loss Function

Tags: r, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

(In R) 
Suppose I have a `loss function`, which takes a function as an input and evaluates it at a (fixed) series of transformations of a fixed data-set.  Is it possible to integrate this into [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) and use it as a custom loss function for
`DNN regression`?  In order to perform Deep Learning, I'm currently using a `tensorflow -> R` interface.

Answer (score 2):

The [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) implementation of R allows you to use a custom loss function. However, the function needs to be implemented using a very specific syntax and should take in `y_true` and `y_pred` parameters. You can find a nice tutorial [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-loss-functions-for-deep-learning-predicting-home-values-with-keras-for-r-532c9e098d1f). The following code would give you some intution:

```
model %>% compile(
  optimizer = "your-choice-of-optimezer",
  loss = custom_loss_function,
  metrics = c("your-choice-of-metric")
)
```

where

```
custom_loss_function <- function(y_true, y_pred) {
  K <- backend()
  ... # define your function using the backend K
}
```